# Field not updating in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a blackjack bot in Discord but my field for the actual result of the game isn't updating

I've tried adding print statements to find the error but that was no help.
This is what I recieved from my print statements

Embed:
Your Cards: 17
3, 3, 1
Dealer's Cards: 24
7, 7, 10
Result
In progress

Print statements:
Reaction received
Player hits
Reaction removed
Reaction received
Player stands

This is where I put the actual prints in my code:

```py
if dealer_total >= 17:
    if dealer_total > 21 or (player_total <= 21 and player_total > dealer_total):
        await handle_win(ctx, accounts, author_id, bet, message, dealer_hand, dealer_total)
        print("Player won. Game over.")
    elif player_total < dealer_total:
        await handle_loss(ctx, accounts, author_id, bet, message, dealer_hand, dealer_total)
        print("Dealer won. Game over.")
    else:
        await handle_tie(ctx, accounts, author_id, bet, message, dealer_hand, dealer_total)
        print("It's a tie. Game over.")
    break
```

Here is my actual code I have currently:

```py
@bot.command(name="blackjack", aliases=["bj"])
async def blackjack_command(ctx, bet: int):
  author_id = str(ctx.author.id)
  accounts = load_accounts()

  if author_id not in accounts:
      await ctx.send("You don't have an account. Use the ,open command to create one.")
      return

  if accounts[author_id]['balance'] < bet:
      await ctx.send("You don't have enough balance to place this bet.")
      return

  accounts[author_id]['balance'] -= bet
  save_accounts(accounts)

  player_hand = [draw_card(), draw_card()]
  dealer_hand = [draw_card(), draw_card()]

  player_total = calculate_total(player_hand)
  dealer_total = calculate_total(dealer_hand[1:])

  embed = discord.Embed(title="", color=0x232428)
  embed.add_field(name=f"Your Cards: {player_total}", value=format_hand(player_hand), inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name=f"Dealer's Cards: {dealer_total}", value=f"{format_hand(dealer_hand[1:])} ??? " , inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Result", value="In progress", inline=False)
  embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar.url)
  embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.imgur.com/JBPnaZz.png")

  message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

  if player_total == 21:
      await handle_win(ctx, accounts, author_id, bet, message, dealer_hand, dealer_total)
      return

  await message.add_reaction("✅")
  await message.add_reaction("❌")

  def check(reaction, user):
      return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["✅", "❌"]

  while True:
      try:
          reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60, check=check)

          if str(reaction.emoji) == "✅":
              player_hand.append(draw_card())
              player_total = calculate_total(player_hand)
              embed.set_field_at(0, name=f"Your Cards: {player_total}", value=format_hand(player_hand), inline=False)
              await message.edit(embed=embed)

              if player_total > 21:
                  await handle_loss(ctx, accounts, author_id, bet, message, dealer_hand, dealer_total)
                  return

          else:
              while dealer_total < 17:
                  dealer_hand.append(draw_card())
                  dealer_total = calculate_total(dealer_hand)

              embed.set_field_at(1, name=f"Dealer's Cards: {dealer_total}", value=format_hand(dealer_hand), inline=False)
              await message.edit(embed=embed)

              if dealer_total >= 17:
                  if dealer_total > 21 or player_total > dealer_total:
                      await handle_win(ctx, accounts, author_id, bet, message, dealer_hand, dealer_total)
                      return
                  elif player_total < dealer_total:
                      await handle_loss(ctx, accounts, author_id, bet, message, dealer_hand, dealer_total)
                      return
                  else:
                      await handle_tie(ctx, accounts, author_id, bet, message, dealer_hand, dealer_total)
                      return

          await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
      except asyncio.TimeoutError:
          await message.delete()
          break

async def handle_win(ctx, accounts, author_id, bet, message, dealer_hand, dealer_total):
  accounts[author_id]['balance'] += bet * 2
  save_accounts(accounts)
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Blackjack", color=0x00FF00)
  embed.add_field(name=f"Your Cards: {format_total(player_hand)}", value=format_hand(player_hand), inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Dealer's Hand", value=format_hand(dealer_hand), inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Result", value=f"You won! New Balance: {accounts[author_id]['balance']}", inline=False)
  embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar.url)
  embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.imgur.com/JBPnaZz.png")
  await message.edit(embed=embed)

async def handle_loss(ctx, accounts, author_id, bet, message, dealer_hand, dealer_total):
  save_accounts(accounts)
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Blackjack", color=0xFF0000)
  embed.add_field(name=f"Your Cards: {format_total(player_hand)}", value=format_hand(player_hand), inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Dealer's Hand", value=format_hand(dealer_hand), inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Result", value=f"You lost! New Balance: {accounts[author_id]['balance']}", inline=False)
  embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar.url)
  embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.imgur.com/JBPnaZz.png")
  await message.edit(embed=embed)

async def handle_tie(ctx, accounts, author_id, bet, message, dealer_hand, dealer_total):
  accounts[author_id]['balance'] += bet
  save_accounts(accounts)
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Blackjack", color=0xFFFF00)
  embed.add_field(name=f"Your Cards: {format_total(player_hand)}", value=format_hand(player_hand), inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Dealer's Hand", value=format_hand(dealer_hand), inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Result", value=f"It's a tie! New Balance: {accounts[author_id]['balance']}", inline=False)
  embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar.url)
  embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.imgur.com/JBPnaZz.png")
  await message.edit(embed=embed)

def draw_card():
  return random.randint(1, 10)

def calculate_total(hand):
  total = sum(hand)
  if total <= 11 and 1 in hand:
      total += 10
  return total

def format_hand(hand):
  return ", ".join(str(card) for card in hand)
```